# How to drop one join key when joining two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have two tables. Both have lot of columns. Now I have a common column called ID on which I would join.

Now since this variable ID is present in both the tables if I do simply this

```
select a.*,b.*
from table_a as a
left join table_b as b on a.id=b.id
```

This will give an error as `id` is duplicate (present in both the tables and getting included for both).

I don't want to write down separately each column of `b` in the select statement. I have lots of columns and that is a pain. Can I rename the ID column of b in the join statement itself similar to SAS data merge statements?

I am using Postgres.

Comment: Not sure what postgreSQL does with using, but if you do the join with a using clause, like:

from a left join b using(id)

the join should have only one column id.  I believe this is what Oracle will do with it

Comment: So you saying using will not give error since both the columns are included?

Comment: No it doesn't. Just checked.

Comment: just a guess, as the join would just have a single column, id, not 2 columns, a.id and b.id

Comment: Can try this out in sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/43ced7/4

Comment: A proper question would include the verbatim error message, valid SQL, table definitions and the Postgres version.

Answer (score 3):

Postgres would *not* give you an error for duplicate output column names in a plain `SELECT`, but some clients do. (Duplicate names are not very useful either way.)

Use the **`USING`** clause as join condition to fold the two join columns into one:

```
SELECT *
FROM  tbl_a  a
LEFT  JOIN tbl_b b USING (id);
```

While you join the same table (self-join) there will be more duplicate column names. The query would make hardly any sense to begin with. This starts to make sense for *different* tables. Like you stated in your question to begin with: `I have two tables ...`

To avoid all duplicate column names, you have to list them in the `SELECT` clause explicitly - possibly dealing out column aliases to get both instances with different names.

Or you can use a **`NATURAL`** join - if that fits your unexplained use case:

```
SELECT *
FROM  tbl_a  a
NATURAL LEFT JOIN tbl_b b;
```

This joins on all columns that share the same name and folds those automatically - exactly the same as listing all common column names in a `USING` clause. You need to be aware of rules for possible `null` values ...

[Details in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM)

Comment: I used using but did 
select a.*,b.* and it gave the same error

Comment: @Manish: With `SELECT a.*, b.*` you would instruct Postgres to output the column twice anyway. Also ..  I added more above.

Comment: @Manish: if you use `SELECT *` with `USING` the common fields (ID in this case) will be merged and there will only be a single `ID` in the result set. [SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/43ced7/7). (This is also an advertisement for why using a common field name such as `ID` in many tables is a Bad Idea. Better to use a constructed field name such as `ID_TBL_A`, `ID_TBL_B`, etc). Best of luck.

Comment: For anyone wondering, USING and ON are mutually exclusive join constraints, at least in SQLite. So, for example, you **cannot** do something like `JOIN USING(id) ON time BETWEEN date1 AND date2`. You would have to resort to `JOIN ON a.id=b.id AND time BETWEEN date1 AND date2` and then you still have OP's problem.