# Filter by count from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, count, aggregate-functions

This query works fine only without `WHERE`, otherwise there is an error:

> column "cnt" does not exist

```
SELECT
  *,
  (SELECT count(*)
   FROM B
   WHERE A.id = B.id) AS cnt
FROM A
WHERE cnt > 0
```

Comment: To get the best solution, you would need to disclose exact table definitions, your version of Postgres and what the query should return *exactly* Do you need *all* columns of `A` and the corresponding count in `B`? Or just some columns - or even just the ID? - and whether ate least one related row exists `B`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM (SELECT A.*,
             (SELECT count(*)
              FROM B
              WHERE A.id = B.id
             ) AS cnt
      FROM A
     ) a
WHERE cnt > 0;
```

Column aliases defined in the `SELECT` cannot be used by the `WHERE` (or other clauses) for that `SELECT`.

Or, if the id on `a` is unique, you can more simply do:

```
SELECT a.*, COUNT(B.id)
FROM A LEFT JOIN
     B
     ON A.id = B.id
GROUP BY A.id
HAVING COUNT(B.id) > 0;
```

Or, if you don't really need the count, then:

```
select a.*
from a
where exists (select 1 from b where b.id = a.id);
```

Comment: To your second query: postgres really allows to have outside aggregate function attributes that are not behind group by?

Comment: @RadimBača . . . Yes.  Postgres implements the ANSI standard (optional) functionality that -- essentially -- when a column is declared as unique then the rest of the columns are not needed.  Here is a SQL Fiddle:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f5859/1.

Comment: @Gordon: That's almost, but not quite true. Works only for PK column(s) in Postgres 9.1 or later. In particular, it does *not* work for UNIQUE or EXCLUSION constraints. Extended fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5dcbf/1

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter . . . Thank you for the clarification.  Clearly, I've only ever done it on primary keys.

Answer (score 2):

#### Assumptions:

- You need all columns from `A` in the result, plus the count from `B`. That's what your demonstrated query does.
- You only want rows with `cnt > 0`. That's what started your question after all.
- Most or all `B.id` exist in `A`. That's the typical case and certainly true if a FK constraint on `B.id` references to `A.id`.

#### Solution

Faster, shorter, correct:

```
SELECT *  -- !
FROM  (SELECT id, count(*) AS cnt FROM B) B
JOIN   A USING (id)  -- !
-- WHERE cnt > 0 -- this predicate is implicit now!
```

#### Major points

- Aggregate *before* the join, that's typically (substantially) faster when processing the whole table or major parts of it. It also defends against problems if you join to more than one *n*-table. See:

  - [Aggregate functions on multiple joined tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261087/aggregate-functions-on-multiple-joined-tables/15261367#15261367)
- You don't need to add the predicate `WHERE cnt > 0` any more, that's implicit with the `[INNER] JOIN`.
- You can simply write `SELECT *`, since the join only adds the column `cnt` to `A.*` when done with the `USING` clause - only one instance of the joining column(s) (`id` in the example) is added to the out columns. See:

  - [How to drop one join key when joining two tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33640223/how-to-drop-one-join-key-when-joining-two-tables/33640296#33640296)

#### Your added [question in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745378/filter-by-count-from-another-table#comment80437152_46745391)

> postgres really allows to have outside aggregate function attributes that are not behind group by?

That's only true if the PK column(s) is listed in the `GROUP BY` clause - which covers the whole row. *Not* the case for a `UNIQUE` or `EXCLUSION` constraint. See:

- [Return a grouped list with occurrences using Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836874/return-a-grouped-list-with-occurrences-using-rails-and-postgresql/11847961#11847961)

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5dcbf/1) (extended version of [Gordon's demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745378/filter-by-count-from-another-table/46750864#comment80437251_46745391)).